# git submodule init within nested submodule

Tags: git, nested, git-submodules, git-clone

I have a git submodule(subproject) with several submodules inside it within a main project. I want to checkout each nested submodule within the main submodule seperately. Also the main project has .gitmodules file with the required git submodule path from the git repo to pull.

Followed the steps below

```
1. git clone mainproject.git
2. git submodule update --init (This would pull the subproject not the complete nested submodules)
3. cd subproject
4. git submodule update --init submodule1(This step does not pull the nested submodule)
This lead to error: pathspec 'submodule1' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

But doing the below steps clones the complete submodule with nested submodules including

```
1. git clone mainproject.git
2. git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Please let me know if there is a way to retrieve the nested submodule within the submodule of a Project.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, reading your question, I can't quite understand what you are looking for. You indicate that `git submodule update --init --recursive`  works correctly, and I would say "fine, this is what you should do". Do you seek to do something different ? can you rephrase your question to clearly state what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to update each nested submodule within the main submodule

Comment: I would answer : "use `git submodule update --init --recursive`". It looks like this isn't the answer you are looking for. Can you describe something you want to do, which isn't covered by this command ?

Comment: Yeah the command mentioned by you pulls the complete submodule including nested submodules in it. I would like to pull each nested submodule using ``` git submodule update --init``` but not recursively.

Comment: ok, `cd subproject; git submodule update --init submodule1` should work. Check that there is no typo in `submodule1`, and that it matches a path listed in the `.gitmodules` of your subproject.